# jQuery.load() in Dart

Tags: jquery, dart

Is there any equivalent function to [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in Dart?

If not; how do I load some parts of my page with AJAX, as an alternative to loading the whole page again? I would like it to seem like people are actually moving to a different page. I was thinking of doing it with a HttpRequest, manipulating the history with the [History class](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/History.html). I'm however missing the spinning wheel in the browser tab and the refresh button becoming unavailable. How can I achieve this?

**Example**: I believe that's what facebook are doing, and maybe also GitHub.

Comment: Although that's a perfectly valid use case, an alternative could be just to load data from the server (using `HttpRequest`), and build the HTML on the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to load the HTML returned by a GET request into a DOM element. In that case, this should work:

```
HttpRequest.getString(uri).then((data) => query("#container").innerHtml = data);
```

Comment: I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, that with this method there will be no indication from the browser, that the page is "loading".

Comment: I am not sure I understand what kind of indication you want. could you please clarify?

Comment: Take chromium for instance. When loading a page the refresh-button will become unavailable and there will show a loading animation in the current tab. Firefox is similar.

Comment: you mean loading the page as after entering an url? I guess it wouldn't, but I believe that `jQuery.load()` doesn't do it either. However, you are using this technique to avoid reloading the page, so I don't see benefit in faking that you acutally do that. Of course you can always show a custom spinner.

Comment: The benefit of doing that is that you don't have to add some spinner on the content being loaded, but instead get the browser to show that new content is being loaded. But I see your point.